# Is there a way via htaccess to change URLs to clean URLs by deleting a parat of an URL?

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

My all URLs formats are like these:

```
http://example.com/category?format=feed
http://example.com/category/sub_category/?format=feed
```

for example: http://example.com/computer/cpu/?format=feed

Is there a way via htaccess to change top URLs to these:

```
http://example.com/category/feed
http://example.com/category/sub_category/feed
```

example1: http://example.com/computer/cpu/feed

example2: http://example.com/computer/feed

Comment: Yes there is a way. See the long list on the right for more info -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules should meet both requirements. But allows you to change the category and subcat as long as the normal URLs don't change and `format` is always a key in the query string.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /$1/$2/?format=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /$1/?format=$2 [L]
```

Then you should be able to use these URL types.

```
http://example.com/category/feed
http://example.com/category/sub_category/feed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...The Clean URL must changes only internally...is that right? but not happen that!

Comment: Yes the clean URL like this `http://example.com/category/feed` is what should show in the address bar. If you used the example code above it should only redirect internally. This `[L]` tells it to stop processing when it matches the rule. Make sure that is all you have there. Don't use the `R`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should achieve what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /$1/$2/%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1? [L,R]
```

The above will turn:

`http://example.com/category?format=feed` to `http://example.com/category/feed`

and

`http://example.com/category/sub_category/?format=feed` to `http://example.com/category/sub_category/feed`